# How to dynamically change ToolbarResource

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing PCL aplication in Xamarin.Forms. 
I want to have a customized toolbar for my main page (with custom layout, logo etc.) and standard toolbars for all other pages (with back button and some `ContentPage.ToolbarItems`).

I created custom file *MainToolbar.axml* in *layouts* folder and wrote 
`ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.MainToolbar;`
in `OnCreate` event handler in *MainActivity.cs*.

Now I can see my custom toolbar not only on main page but on all pages. I try to write `ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;` in `OnDisappearing` event handler of the main page, but it doesn't affect. So how can I change the toolbar back to standard? I don't have android renderers for all pages and I think there is must be a better way. Thanks.

Comment: How can you access ToolbarResource in your Forms page?

Comment: @YuriS, you guessed my next sub-task :) As first approach (rough, I know) I want to create some kind of static property in App.cs, change it in android click handlers and propagate an event, for which I can subcribe in Forms page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer you cannot change the whole toolbar but you can develop 2 layouts: main and not main and programatically set their visibility in a single toolbar widget or add/remove them from the toolbar. I would do it this way. In PCL in your main page

```
        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();

            MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", "notmain");
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", "main");
        }
```

In your MainActivity after you initialize Forms

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());

            var mainToolbarLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.toolbarMainLayout);
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", (page, toolbar) =>
            {
                if (toolbar == "main")
                {
                     mainToolbarLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    mainToolbarLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }

            });
    }
```

Here is a sample of Toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
  >

  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarMainLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Yuri S, thank you. Idea with visibility changing looks pretty. But the main question remains - *where* should I do it? If I have no definite layout in android sub-project, I cannot proceed `OnPause` and `OnResume` handlers. Or in my case I *must* create layout for main activity at least?

Comment: Edited my answer. Some people don't like MessagingCenter so they would suggest to pass somehow Activity (or handler or interface), so it is known by your PCL probably using Dependency service  but I prefer simple approach in this case. If you don't want MessagingCenter you can use interface like SetMainToolbar and implement it in all systems if you need more than just Android

Comment: I'm confusing a bit with *after you initialize Forms* phrase. Does it mean `OnCreate` handler? But it hasn't `LayoutInflater.Inflate` line like java app. I cannot use `FindViewById` in `OnCreate` - it returns null...

Comment: After Forms.Init(). Where do you see Inflater in my code? You have to create linear layout with toolbarMainLayout ID inside Resource.Layout.Toolbar. Added to my answer

Comment: Yuri, I did the same. But now I copy your code as-is, and have an error *Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed*. This error gone after adding `base.OnCreate(bundle);` in begin of constructor, but `FindViewById` still returns null (toolbar example is copied too and I have this Id). It seems, I have some mistakes in application architecture or some settings are missing.

Comment: My activity declared as ` [Activity(Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener`. I use Xamarin packages v.23.3.0 and Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247.

Comment: why you are adding base.onCreate in constructor? it is a separate override function of activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149897/discussion-between-miamy-and-yuri-s).

Comment: Yuri,thanks for your help. It was a news for me that MessagingCenter can be used for exchange between Forms and platform app's parts - and it is a good news!

Comment: Read my comment above, some people don't like it but it is very good tool, I like it

Comment: Sorry, the comment I mentioned is in another answer :-) Please read what others say about Messenger. Most people like it

Comment: it works well for me but there is no indication to fill the green zone. Can someone help me? Thank you